# Is there practical reasoning to enforce JDK version for build?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

There exists [maven enforcer plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html) which can enforce build to be run only on specific JDK version.

I wonder if there any practical reasoning to have this? 
We have already build configuration to specify source and target versions. As far as I understand this should be more than enough, because Java is backward compatible. For example how it looks in gradle:

```
compileJava   {
  sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
  targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
```

That's how it looks in maven:

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

If you have seen any reason to require exact jdk version - could you please also write it down.

UPD.
question is more about if there is any practical difference to compile project of java source/target of version 8 with JDK's of 8,9,10 or 11...

Comment: Well for example, I can't compile JDK 8 streams with JDK 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason for this might be some better optimizations in the compiler of the newer JDK. So even though the target bytecode *level* is the same as with the older compiler, the target bytecode itself might be improved.

[According to Brian Goetz](https://twitter.com/t_linkowski/status/1058815791859224578), this pulls its weight:

> There are times when a better translation from source code to bytecode is made possible by JVM improvements.  For example, prior to 5, `Foo.class` was translated to reflective call; after, to LDC.
>
> So, you may reasonably want to stick to a given language level across an org (because of shared code) but specific apps can still take advantage of VM improvements.

---

*Edit*: Sorry! The quoted tweet is about compiling with source **lower** than target (e.g. `-source 8 -target 11`), so it's different to what the OP asked about. Still, perhaps the newer compiler can produce better bytecode even when the target remains unchanged.

---

PS. As advised by [Basil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496735/is-there-practical-reasoning-to-enforce-jdk-version-for-build/54496894#comment95799245_54496786), let me mention the [javac `--release` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__GUID-D343F6B4-3FDD-43A8-AD24-43DD70214471) of JDK 9+, which prevents from using APIs of the newer JDKs while sticking to older language levels.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all. *Source* is mainly about syntax. *Target* is about the specific byte code magic number and capabilities.

But you could very well write Java 7 conforming code that uses a single class X that only jdk 8 or newer provides. When you then use a Java 8 jdk, that compiler will find that class X and build fine. But when running that code on a Java 7 jvm, the Java 8 class X is missing, leading to a runtime exception.

So: forcing the jdk prevents you from using classes that were added to Java after your target version.

Comment: my question is not about compiling new code with old versions but vice versa - compile old code with newest jdk's

Comment: With respect to this answer it's worth to mention the [javac `--release` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__GUID-D343F6B4-3FDD-43A8-AD24-43DD70214471) of JDK 9+, which prevents from using APIs of the newer JDKs.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski I suggest including this `--release` flag info in an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are multiple reasons. The one I would point out is deployment in an enterprise environment.

Lets say you have thousands of maintained machines running in a company, you just cannot install every single version of java on every computer.  Also security usually doesn't allow downloading(often no direct internet access at all) and every single Java version available needs to be maintained regarding security - with a lot of paperwork and discussion(e.g. security).

Botomline is: In an enterprise you have a very limited set of available Java versions and often not the bleeding edge.

Now, lets say the available version is Java 8. Now if you want the aplication to run in the environment you have to ensure, that it actually runs on the available version (like Java 8). If it would use something not available in that version, it will just not run or crash. In essence such an application simply would be not usable in the enterprise. Meaning the enterprise would look for a different solution, they can actually use in their environment.

So being able to tell the compiler the target version helps a lot to create an application that can and will be actually used(and doesn't crash on a users machine).